# How check if a dataframe cell includes the values and then populate field based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe column with values such as:

```
   Column_1(String are present in a cell with space in between)
ABC DEF EFG HIJ  
ZCG VHT UIO QAR
ABC KLM MNO STU
DEF KLM ABD EFG
```

I need to populate the values based on the condition:

```
if Column_1 includes ABC and not KLM then 1
if Column_1 includes KLM and not ABC then 2
if Column_1 includes both ABC and KLM then 3
if Column_1 does not include both ABC and KLM then 4
```

SO Column_1 becomes:

```
  Column_1
    1
    4
    3
    2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
mapper = {
    (True, False): 1,
    (False, True): 2,
    (True, True): 3,
    (False, False): 4,
}
df["Value"] = df["Column_1"].apply(lambda x: mapper[("ABC" in x, "KLM" in x)])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
          Column_1  Value
0  ABC DEF EFG HIJ      1
1  ZCG VHT UIO QAR      4
2  ABC KLM MNO STU      3
3  DEF KLM ABD EFG      2
```

Comment: You are the best!!